# Condition number for a nonlinear matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, condition-number

Is there such a thing as a condition number for a nonlinear (polynomial) matrix in multiple variables, and if so, is it something simple (I doubt it) or maybe there are multiple methods?

Equations such as:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_i      & a_{i2} & a_{i3} & a_{i11} & b_i & b_{i3} & b_{i11} & c_i & c_{i11} & d_i\\
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
x^2\\
xy \\
xz \\
x  \\
y^2\\
yz \\
y  \\
z^2\\
z  \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
=0
\end{equation}
for $i = 1,2,3$.